# Use ckeditor in modern mobile browsers

Tags: ckeditor

I use ckeditor in my site: [https://times.mk.ua/](https://times.mk.ua/home/ckc)[1](https://times.mk.ua/home/ckc): https://times.mk.ua/

here code:

```
   CKEDITOR.replace('ae-textarea-text', {       
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/Record/Upload?waterMarkOn=01',
    height: 650,
    width: 950

});
```

but in modern browsers ckeditor don't shows

here test url - [enter link description here]https://times.mk.ua/home/ckc[1](https://times.mk.ua/home/ckc)

Answer (score 0):

You're using version "4.3.1", that's very old and won't work properly with mobile browsers.